# Can someone please explain adding custom Permissions? (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-admin

I am using Django 1.9 and I am trying to add a permission for a group to only be able to view certain models in the admin panel.

I have found this in the Django Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions 
But I don't understand how it works if Django 1.9 does not include support for a view only permission. How does it know what view_task is supposed to do?

How would I go about implementing this? Do I need to write code elsewhere to define what a view permission is?

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("view_task", "Can see available tasks"),
            ("change_task_status", "Can change the status of tasks"),
            ("close_task", "Can remove a task by setting its status as closed"),
        )
```

Comment: I think you also can just use the default permissions given from django. In the admin you can set the permissions of a group that they can for example not view a single model. If set, it doesn't appear in the admin for them. No need for custom permissions in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @wfehr. The view permission was only added to the admin panel in Django 2.2. I am using version 1.9, so unfortunately it is not that simple.

Comment: 1.9 is insecure and unsupported. You should upgrade.